# Animate doesn't work

Tags: plotting, animation

I'm trying to animate plot:[image]

a, A, B and C are constants. So I wrote the following script:

```
a:=1;
E1:=1.6*10^(-19);
E2:=1.6*10^(-19);
E3:=1.6*10^(-19);
h = 6.63*10^-34;
f[x_,t_] = (Sqrt[a]/2) (((10/16) Sin[Pi (x/a)])/E^(I (E1 (t/h)))
            - ((5/16) Sin[3 Pi (x/a)])/E^(I (E2 (t/h)))
            + ((1/16) Sin[5 Pi (x/a)])/E^(I (E3 (t/h))));
Animate[Plot[f[x,t],{x,0,a}, Filling ->Bottom, AxesLabel ->Automatic],
        {t,0,100, 1},AnimationRunning->False]
```

I get empty graph. Okay, maybe my function is not right, so I've tried `f[x_,t_] = Sin(x*t);` And again, the graph is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don’t use _ in the animate

Comment: you need to define `h` and also as @CarlWoll pointed, use `f[x,t]` inside `Plot`. Also make sure `f[x,t]` returns real value.

Comment: @Sumit h isn't defined as Planck constant?

Comment: @Russiancold you should define the Planck constant as `hbar = UnitConvert@Quantity[None, "PlanckConstant"]` if you want to use its numerical value.

Comment: `h isn't defined as Planck constant?` Mathematica does not know that `h` is supposed to be Planck constant. You can do `?h` to find out. Also, if it were, Mathematica uses `UpperCase` for such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to see the superposition of three different wavefunctions here is your answer.

```
a = 1;
E1 = 1.6*10^(-19);
E2 = 2.6*10^(-19);
E3 = 3.6*10^(-19);
h =  6.63*10^-34;
f[x_, t_] := (Sqrt[a]/ 2) (((10/16) Sin[Pi (x/a)])/ E^(I (E1 (t/h)))
               - ((5/16) Sin[3 Pi (x/a)])/ E^(I (E2 (t/h))) 
               + ((1/16) Sin[5 Pi (x/a)])/E^(I (E3 (t/h))));

Animate[Plot[Abs[f[x, t]]^2, {x, 0, a}, Filling -> Bottom, PlotRange -> {0, 0.25},
        AxesLabel -> Automatic], {t, 0, 100, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

To make sure `f[x,t]` returns real value I use `Abs[]` in the `Plot`. If `E1=E2=E3` then you will not see any variation in time.

As José Antonio Díaz Navas pointed out, you can set the value of Planck's constant `h` by `QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert@Quantity[None, "PlanckConstant"]` as well.

Comment: Thanks, so comparing to my script you removed "_" and defined h to make it work, right? Why Abs[] but not Re[]?

Comment: Your function `f[x,t]` is complex. It is up to you to choose the real part, $\Re$ `Re[]`, and/or the imaginary part, $\Im$ `Im[]`, or `Abs[]`

Comment: That's due to my quantum mechanical habit of using $|/Psi|^2$ :)

Comment: @Sumit it's just my misunderstanding of Abs, somehow I forgot what is absolute value of complex number. Of course I need Abs but not Real part here.

Comment: @Sumit is there any way to make the animation smoother or it's caused by this certain function? I'm trying to change dt param, but animation is still rough. Btw it's psi-function)

Comment: Most probably you need to use a smaller step size for `t`, say `{t,0,0.001,0.0001}` and/or to use `AnimationRate` and set more frame per second. Hard to say without looking at actual parameters.